# AWS DMS - Migrating from SQL Server to S3 Bucket. How I can add the header in the .csv?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration, aws-dms

I had success migrating the tables from SQL server to .csv in s3 but I can't get it to **include a header with column names**. How can I do it?

I did it with AWS DMS:

- Source endpoint: SQL Server
- Target endpoint: S3
- I have created a Replication Instance and a Task
- I ran the task successfully and the .csv was created in the S3 Bucket with the data but not with the header with the column names.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

In the Target Endpoint I add the parameter **addColumnName=true;** in the Endpoint-specific settings.

[image]